# Is there a python package to Read and update metadata from AVI, MP4 and MKV?

Tags: python, package

Does a python package exist for changing the metadata from video files like AVI, MP4 and MKV?

I google a lot of stuff, but much of this was outdatet or only for pictures or audio files.

Tried to read the headers of the files but got only binarys.

Is a python package available to change 'Title, Genre, Year .. ' in the files?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tinytag python package to access read the media files meta data.
kindly refer the below library.
https://pypi.org/project/tinytag/

Comment: Thank you,

Sadly it is for read only and supports only mp4, not the other media types.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the metadata of the media file , you can use the python's exif package.
https://pypi.org/project/exif/

Comment: Thank you,

Sadly it is for read only and supports only mp4, not the other media types.